How can I add an XML page with vike (ssr) to my website?
For my website I use vike for ssr. For SEO, I would like to add a sitemap in XML format. However, vike builds my pages in html format. Is there a way in which I can enter the XML file for SEO?
I tried to access the xml file via the vike router, which did not work. I also had the idea of writing a function in the render folder that returns the xml page and is then called instead of +onRenderHtml when the sitemap is called. But I couldn't manage that.

For our statically generated site, we currently hand-edit our sitemap.xml in the public directory, which is copied to dist at build time by vite.
There are a number of sitemap generators out there, but we just followed the examples at sitemap.org and it was relatively straightforward. It's not entirely clear from the question whether that is sufficient or whether you're looking for something automated.
Manual updates work reasonably well for our specific use case, but we're also looking at automating it, and there appear to be a few ways to accomplish this.
Options we're experimenting with for automation:

Using a separate plugin (we're specifically looking at vite-plugin-sitemap)

Using a completely separate post-processing CLI tool (e.g. sitemap) called as an npm script within package.json

Rendering it in onPrerenderStart (...probably also using sitemap, as a library rather than a CLI)


Edit: There is an open low-pri Vike issue #1525 for a new onRenderContent hook for this purpose, and a recommended interim workaround of using a post-build script.
